# Map struct mapper not adding Many to One column for mapping

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

For my spring-boot application I want to convert DTO columns to entity object for that I am using mapstruct mapper class. but it is not converting my ManyToOne column to entity object. how can I add that
below is my Entity class

```
@Entity(name = "favorite_rooms")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Favorite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_fav_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_fav_id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "animal_id")
    Animal animal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Room rooms;
}
```

below my code generated by mapper class

```
public List<Favorite> favoriteDtosToFavorite(Set<FavoriteDto> favoriteRooms) {
        if (favoriteRooms == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            List<Favorite> list = new ArrayList(favoriteRooms.size());
            Iterator var3 = favoriteRooms.iterator();

            while(var3.hasNext()) {
                FavoriteDto favoriteDto = (FavoriteDto)var3.next();
                list.add(this.favoriteDtoToFavorite(favoriteDto));
            }

            return list;
        }
    }

    protected Favorite favoriteDtoToFavorite(FavoriteDto favoriteDto) {
        if (favoriteDto == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Favorite favorite = new Favorite();
            favorite.setId(favoriteDto.getId());
            return favorite;
        }
    }
```

as I see it not adding my animal and room data
can any one please let me know how to add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the mapping methods for each child object. See [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/index.html#mapping-object-references).

```java
@Mapper
public interface FavoriteMapper {
    FavoriteMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(FavoriteMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    Favorite mapFavorite(FavoriteDTO favoriteDTO);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
    Animal mapAnimal(AnimalDTO animalDTO);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
    Room mapRoom(RoomDTO animalDTO);

    List<Favorite> favoriteDtosToFavorite(Set<FavoriteDTO> favoriteDTOSet);
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class FavoriteMapperImpl implements FavoriteMapper {

    @Override
    public Favorite mapFavorite(FavoriteDTO favoriteDTO) {
        if ( favoriteDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Favorite favorite = new Favorite();

        favorite.setId( favoriteDTO.getId() );
        favorite.setAnimal( mapAnimal( favoriteDTO.getAnimal() ) );
        favorite.setRooms( mapRoom( favoriteDTO.getRooms() ) );

        return favorite;
    }

    @Override
    public Animal mapAnimal(AnimalDTO animalDTO) {
        if ( animalDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Animal animal = new Animal();

        animal.setId( animalDTO.getId() );
        animal.setName( animalDTO.getName() );

        return animal;
    }

    @Override
    public Room mapRoom(RoomDTO animalDTO) {
        if ( animalDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Room room = new Room();

        room.setId( animalDTO.getId() );
        room.setName( animalDTO.getName() );

        return room;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Favorite> favoriteDtosToFavorite(Set<FavoriteDTO> favoriteDTOSet) {
        if ( favoriteDTOSet == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Favorite> list = new ArrayList<Favorite>( favoriteDTOSet.size() );
        for ( FavoriteDTO favoriteDTO : favoriteDTOSet ) {
            list.add( mapFavorite( favoriteDTO ) );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

DTO used:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class FavoriteDTO {

    Long id;

    AnimalDTO animal;

    RoomDTO rooms;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class AnimalDTO {
    Long id;
    String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class RoomDTO {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

Entities used:

```java
@Entity(name = "favorite_rooms")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Favorite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_fav_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_fav_id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "animal_id")
    Animal animal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Room rooms;
}

@Entity(name = "favorite_animal")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_fav_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_fav_id")
    Long id;

    String name;
}

@Entity(name = "favorite_room")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_fav_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_fav_id")
    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

Comment: why we need to create separate mapper class?

Comment: It is according to documentation. See details https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/index.html#mapping-object-references. I added this link to answer